# What search algorithm or a data structure would you suggest?

Tags: java, algorithm, search, sorting

I have a big number of `SortedSet<Long>` structures:

```
1, 2, 5, 8, 10, 35, 77, ...
5, 9, 35, 50, 132, ...
2, 4, 8, 15, 17, 23, ...
... hundreds of thousands of such rows...
```

I need to find a number that goes after, say, `50`. In this example (if there are just three sets) it is `77`. The number of sets is huge - hundreds of thousands. What algorithm would you suggest?

Comment: Do you mean that you want the next value after a given value (`50`) of the merged lists?

Comment: Yes, exactly, from the "merged list"

Comment: What if 77 occurs in multiple sets? Do you care which sets, or are you just trying to find the next highest number in ANY set?  Also, what if a different set contains 50?  Is that instance of 50 "next", or is it the "next member strictly larger than the 'current' value"?  Your question is underspecified.

Comment: You also fail to mention if the sets are going to be updated between queries.  If not, just creating a merged sorted set of values is all you need.

Comment: (1) Can you give us some idea of the size of each set? (2) How many such queries to you need to run? (3) Can the sets change between queries, or are they set in stone?

Comment: I don't care where exactly that 77 value is found, I just need to finds it absolute value

Comment: Sets are stable. Sets may contain hundreds of thousands of numbers. I want to find the most efficient implementation - plain `for` is my last resort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly here is my idea:

```
Collection<SortedSet<Long>> sets = //...

long minAfter50 = Long.MAX_VALUE;
for (SortedSet<Long> set : sets) {
    final Long first = set.tailSet(51L).first();
    minAfter50 = Math.min(minAfter50, first);
}
```

Here is the idea:

- iterate over all input sets
- crop all values less then or equal 50
- take the first argument of the cropped set (guaranteed to be greater than 50)
- calcualte the smallest value out of those collected in previous step

UPDATE (based on *@beerbajay* comment): if SortedSet is actually a `TreeSet`, the following code might perform better. Also I am making sure that there is any value greater than 50 in each and every set:

```
long minAfter50 = Long.MAX_VALUE;
for (TreeSet<Long> set : sets) {
    final Long higher = set.higher(50L);
    if (higher != null && higher < minAfter50) {
        minAfter50 = higher;
    }
}
```

Comment: This would seem to be the most efficient way to do it, given that all the SortedSets are already created. Merging them or creating any other data structure is surely less efficient.

Comment: If you're using `TreeSet` as your `SortedSet` implementation, you can avoid the cost of creating the view in `tailSet()` by using [`higher()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#higher%28E%29) instead. `first = set.higher(50l);`

Comment: @beerbajay: I updated my answer based on your valuable input, hope you don't mind

Comment: Yep.  You're not going to find a more efficient implementation.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: can you prove it somehow? The current solution (second one) is `O(n logn)`.

Comment: Well...there are two variables: the number of sets (`m`) and their sizes (`n`).  This solution is `O(m log n)`.  It's clear that you have to look at each of the `m` sets at least once, and it's also clear that you can't determine anything about the values in that set above `50` in less than `O(log n)`.  That's a bit handwavy, but I think I'm convinced.

Answer (score 1):

If that's all the precomputation you allow, then the only thing you can do is call tailSet on each SortedSet and find the minimum.

If you allow some extra data structures, the easiest thing to do is keep track of the union of all the sets and then you just have to call tailSet on that.

I suspect neither is the answer you want.  Perhaps you could better describe the constraints you have?

Comment: Right, none of these options are good for me. Mostly because they are too slow. I'm looking for some trick here. I don't have any constraints.

Comment: @Keith's second option is the "trick". That is, use a different data structure _instead_ of a list of sorted sets. For example, a sorted set of (value, listID) pairs. Now the look-up is O(log(mn)) for m lists of n values instead of O(m log n).

Comment: If you don't have any constraints, then precompute a `HashMap` from every value to its next higher value.  `O(1)`.  (Precompute by putting all the values in an array, sorting them, and entering each adjacent pair in the `HashMap`.)

Answer (score 0):

set is implemented as a binary search tree, the largest number always in the last.
you can search number bigger than 50 easier, always get the 1st number bigger than 50 in each set.